# Loading Application.Resources properly in WPF / XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF Application, I specify an Application.Resource, as shown here:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp" [...]>
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:MyData x:Key="MyData">
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have a class `MyData`, which currently does all of its initialization (including loading data from a file) in its constructor.   I consider this bad form, as I'm coming from a C++ background, where constructors should be kept minimal.

I suspect I want the MyData class to listen for an event, something like "AfterResourcesLoaded", but I haven't been able to find any description of this in searching MSDN.

- Am I right that doing too much work in the constructor is bad form in C#, as it is in C++? Or is it acceptable to do significant work in the constructor?
- How do I register an event-handler in MyData in the XAML, so that I can do the necessary work when the event is triggered, after the object is constructed?

(or perhaps I'm on the wrong track entirely?  Alternative ideas gratefully considered.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing too much work in the constructor of a class is also bad idea in C# as well as in C++ (mainly because it is not obvious for the users of the class).

What you can do is to have the data load triggered when it is accessed for the first time (e.g. in a property getter of the `MyData` class) or by providing an explicit method (e.g. `LoadData`) that can be called in the Application.Startup event handler. Something like this:

```
public class MyApp : Application
{
   public override OnStartup(EventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnStartup(e);

       MyData data = FindResource("MyData");

       data.LoadData();       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MyData is basically a simple class that just holds data, I'd move the responsibility of loading MyData out of itself and into another class. The other class could hydrate MyData in your application or Window's Loaded event.